# Find all unique combinations for all possible group sizes

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I know that if I want to find out the number of combinations for set then I can use this formula as long as I have a fixed number of values being compared at a time (I have to have a set r value).

$$n!\over k!\,(n-k)!$$

I'm looking to find out what the formula would if I wanted to know the sum of all values for r between 1 and n.

For example if my data set is just:

- Red
- Green
- Blue

Then I can have 7 unique groupings if I want to look at all possible group sizes (excluding an empty group):

- Red
- Green
- Blue
- Red, Green
- Red, Blue
- Green, Blue
- Red, Green, Blue

Comment: Well, you may find the values for some small $n$ manually and see if it rings a bell. Keep in mind that 0 is a perfectly valid group size.

Comment: Your edit introduced an undefined variable $k$.

Comment: Hi Ivan.  That's true.  I can always -1 from my result so that doesn't bother me too much. The problem in this case is that my n value is very high.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you allow the empty set, each of Red, Blue, and Green can be in the group (subset) or not, so there are $2^3=8$ subsets.  You made three binary choices to define the subset.  Subtract the empty set you excluded and you have $7$.  For any $n$, there are $2^n-1$ non-empty subsets of $n$ items by the same logic.

Comment: I spent an embarrassing amount of time on this only to not figure that out.  Thanks!